# Access <script> tag from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to access < script type='text/javascript' ....>< / script >  existing within Head tag.

What I was doing to achieve that,

```
    foreach (Control ctrl in Header.Controls)
    {          
            Response.Write(ctrl.GetType() + "<br/>");
    }
```

It gives me the reference of "title", "meta" and "literal" control. How can I get the  control and get the "src" attribute of that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `<script>` tag have `runat="server"`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
No, it does not have.

Comment: @Hoque: you should try adding it!

Comment: I can get access of <meta> tag, <link> tag using the above way but unfortunately I can not get access of <script> tag. 

I would like to do without adding "runat='server'" . But if there is no other way I have to add the "runat" attribute.

Comment: As I have no response, I am going to use runat attribute to access <script> tag. Thanks to Egrunin.